# phaser.io How to use state independent assets globally

Tags: javascript, caching, html5-canvas, ecmascript-5, phaser-framework

I’d like to add images/sprites preloaded in state `a` into `phaserGameInstance.world` after switching to state `b` (where `phaserGameInstance` is an instance of `Phaser.Game`).

Since all assets are stored globally in the browser cache and in `phaserGameInstance.cache` they should be available in all states, but they’re actually not.

The workaround I found out for this is extending the cache object of state `b` with the properties of the cache object of state `a` which is kinda disturbing and probably not the intended way:

```
var priorCache = phaserGameInstance.state.getCurrentState().cache; // State 'a'

phaserGameInstance.state.start('b'); // Switch to state 'b'

jQuery.extend( // Merges the cache of state 'a' recursively
  true,        // into the cache of the current state 'b'
  phaserGameInstance.state.getCurrentState().cache,
  priorCache
);
```

I have not tested whether or not this works when also preloading assets in state `b` (maybe the merging process will overwrite properties of state `b`) but since I’m only preloading my stuff once in state `a` this is the fix I’m currently using.

How is it possible to use preloaded assets independently of their states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `phaserGameInstance.state.start('b')` does not actually switch the states from `a` to `b`. It just assigns state `b` as the pending state to be switched to. That means it is somehow an asynchronous method.

Adding objects to `phaserGameInstance.world` right after calling `phaserGameInstance.state.start('b')` will add the objects into state `a` while state `b` is still pending and will be activated in the next game update. After that update occurred `phaserGameInstance.world` is empty since all objects will be removed when state `a` shuts down. So there is no need to merge the cache or anything.

Here is the solution:

```
phaserGameInstance.state.add(
  'b',
  {
    create: function () { // Add the assets loaded in state 'a' here ...
        phaserGameInstance.add.image(0, 0, 'myImage');
      }
  }
);

phaserGameInstante.state.start('b');

// ... not here! State 'a' is still active in this line.
```

Since the objects were added into state `a` it seemed that they’d be dependent on the states they have been preloaded in but they’re actually state independent as supposed in my question.